# Cannot access HTML DOM in react useEffect return function, for cleanup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, react-hooks, removeeventlistener

I am using a 3rd Party script in my react app, that script is using pure JS to append HTML elements in my webpage. The library attaches a `mw` function to the `window` object and we can then perform various operations like `'init'` and `'cleanup'`.

The init function runs pretty normally and shows a widget UI, but the clenup function is trying to access dom to `removeEventListeners` but cannot find the dom.

Code:

```js
const ThirdPartyWidget = () => {

  useEffect(() => {
    if (window.mw) {
      window.mw("init", { elementId: "widget-element" });
    }

    return () => {
      if (window.mw) {
        window.mw("cleanup");
      }
    };
  }, []);

  return <div id="widget-element"></div>;
};

export default ThirdPartyWidget;
```

I am getting the following error,

[image]

What i know is the cleanup function is trying to access the dom and remove eventlisteners that it had attached. But it is not able to do so.

The library is accessing the correct DOM element as when i try to access the DOM using the same querySelector path in chrome dev tools console i can access them. There is something that i am missing in the core concepts of react lifecycle and cleanups that is causing the problem.

What can i do now?

**Main Question Here is >> Does react run the useEffect cleanUp return function after clearing up the DOM for that component?**

PS. useRef and DOM references cannot be used here sadly as it is a 3rd Party LIB.

Comment: " Does react run the useEffect cleanUp return function after clearing up the DOM for that component" - [Yes](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#parameters)

Comment: Thank You for the doc reference, Is there any more references/blogs/tutorials where i can read more about it.

Comment: Does the 3rd party lib provide you any way to check if the DOM element exists, or provide you access to it? The specific part in the docs is this part: _"After your component is removed from the DOM, React will run your cleanup function"_, I'm not aware of any other articles that go through this though.